# Using Partition by to remove dupes

Tags: rank

I'm trying to figure out how I can remove duplicates in a table while also retaining any changes that may have occurred on different dates.  So if you take my example below, what I've done so far is partition by my distinct list of fields (excluding date), order by date ascending and then rank them accordingly.  Note I have more fields and rows but have condensed it down for easier readability.

Typically I would simply query the rows with Ranking = 1 because this returns my true distinct list of fields AND at the time it most recently changed which is what I want.  However I'm also trying to capture unique changes as they have occurred over time.  Seeing that the State reverted back to "NJ" on 2017-03-11, I therefore need to find a way to keep that record.  So my final result set would include the dates of 2016-11-08, 2016-11-09 and 2017-03-11.  I'm stuck right now so I would appreciate suggestions.  Thanks!

```
Ranking = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY
                                  [State]
                                 ,[DomicileCountryCode]
                                ,[DomicileCountryname]
                        ORDER BY FullDate ASC)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more searching, I was able to find an answer on a different forum.  Hopefully it's okay to post the link here.  Basically it creates two different ROW_NUMBER fields that you can group by to create your unique subset. Then in my top SELECT statement I use MIN to get back the first available date for those 3 subsets.  The link below will provide a clear example.  Very elegant and very nice solution.

[T-SQL to Group time interval change by date range in sql server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171106/t-sql-to-group-time-interval-change-by-date-range-in-sql-server)